# How to interpret the training loss curves in Soft-Actor-Critic (SAC)?

Tags: deep-rl, actor-critic-methods, loss, soft-actor-critic, learning-curve

I am using stable-baseline3 implementation of the Soft-Actor-Critic (SAC) algorithm. The plotted training curves look promising. However, I am not fully sure how to interpret the actor and critic losses. The entropy coefficient $\alpha$ is automatically learned during training. As the entropy decreases, the critic loss and actor loss decrease as well.

- How does the entropy coefficient affect the losses?
- Can this be interpreted as the estimations becoming more accurate as the focus is shifted from exploration to exploitation?
- How can negative actor losses be interpreted, what do actor losses tell in general?

[image]

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: I am getting negative actor loss in SAC implementation from stable-baseline3. Anything on this?

Comment: @devilinthedetail that's expected and good, if expected return is positive :)